# How to get data from the StreamBuilder into the swipable cards from firestore in flutter?

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I'm trying to display data in swipable cards through `StreamBuilder`. But it shows nothing no data on swipable cards. But when I try to display that data in list or column it displays:

```
Container(
  width: 320,
  height: 457,
  child: StreamBuilder(
    stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance
      .collection('posts')
      .snapshots(),
    builder: (BuildContext context,
      AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
          return CircularProgressIndicator();
        }
        if (!snapshot.hasData || snapshot.data == null) {
          return Expanded(child: Text("Empty"));
        }

        final data = snapshot.data!;
        return ListView.builder(
          itemCount: data.size,
          itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
            final document = data.docs[index];
            return Card(
              child: AppinioSwiper(cards: [Text(document['name'])]),
            );
          },
        );
      },
    ),
  )
)
```